como abrir el libro personal de macros en la carpeta de inicio para poder grabar?
Estoy realizando una grabación en macro y le indico guardar macro en " LIBRO DE MACROS PERSONAL " y me sale un mensaje " el libro de macros personal en la carpeta de inicio debe estar abierto para grabar"
Probe de todo retirando la pestaña del " DESARROLLADOR " de la cinta de opciones y volverlo a agregar y nada , no pude encontrar la ruta de libro personal guardado anteriormente.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Asegurate que tienes libro de macros personal. Por defecto se guarda en C:\Users\user name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Excel\XLStart
